# .Net 6 : ServiceStack IAppSettings returns Null while accessing value from Appsettings.json

Tags: c#, microservices, .net-6.0, servicestack

I am facing issue while accessing value from Appsettings.json in service.

Technology stack : Microservice with ServiceStack.core :5.12.0, C#, .Net 6

I am trying to access values from following Appsettings.json

```
{
  "username" : "test@test.com"
}
```

Following is my config

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {               
        services.AddSingleton<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
    }
```

Configure method :

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
          app.UseServiceStack(
                new HttpServiceHost
                {
                  AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
                });
    }
```

Host Class :

```
 public class HttpServiceHost : AppHostBase
   {
      public HttpServiceHost () : base("Test Service" , typeOf(somehandler).assembly){}
   }
```

I am trying to access appsettings in class TestConfig constructor (not handler)  as follows

```
public class TestConfig 
{
    public class TestConfig (IAppSettings setting)
    {
       // This always comes as null 
       this.UserName = setting.GetString("username")

       // But this returns the value 
       this.UserName = HostContext.AppSettings.GetString("username")

    }

    public string UserName {get;set;}   
}
```

Following is the call to TestConfig

```
var testConfig = new TestConfig (new AppSeetings())
```

How to make IAppSettings setting to return appsettings value ?

Note : I am upgrading service to NET 6 from .Net framework 4.5 where it works without any issue.

Thanks!